# How to call post services using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

When i click on a button it should update in the database.

```
<c:forEach items="${listTrips}" var="trip">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <label class="control-label">
            <c:out value="${trip.tripType}  @ ${trip.startTime} " />
            <img src='<c:url value="/resources/images/gray_icon.png"/>' id="button" class="forImg" style="margin-left: 100px;" />
        </label>
        <span> <c:out value="${trip.date} @ ${trip.firstPickupPoint }" /></span>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="${trip.trip_id}" id="button"> <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;
            <i class="fa fa-taxi"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="${trip.trip_id}" onclick="notreport(this)"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-taxi"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
    <hr style="border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;  width: 280px;">
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Assuming you mean the submit button? 
1. change the `"submit"`to `"button"`. 2: `$(function() { $("#button").on("click",function() { $.post("url",{parm1:....,parm2:...},function(data){  alert(data) });});});`

Answer (score 3):

```
  $.post("Backend Function Name", Data in Json format, Call Back Function (eg :function(data, status){alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);});)
```

this is shorthand for post request